# Pedagogical term "adverbial" is covered with which terms in generative grammar?

Tags: terminology

In Pedagogical grammars (like [Oxford Learner's Pocket Grammar](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7533034)) [possible simple sentence structures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(linguistics)#Predicative,_subject_and_object_complements) are divided into the categories presented below:

```
SV      subject, verb
SVO     subject, verb, object
SVC     subject, verb, subject complement
SVA     subject, verb, adverbial
SVOO    subject, verb, indirect object, direct object
SVOC    subject, verb, object, object complement
SVOA    subject, verb, object, adverbial
```

And also these kind of grammars say that we can add extra adverbials to the clause structures.

In generative grammar which terms cover the Pedagogical term adverbial?

Comment: Probably just adjunct?